# "foreach" does not filter specific controls

Tags: c#, foreach

I encountered a strange behavior of C# which I do not quite understand.
I have a simple RichTextBox coloring code like:

```
foreach (RichTextBox rtb in groupBoxOutputs.Controls)
                        {
                            rtb.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                            rtb.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        }
```

When I run the code and it encounters a Button (or any other non-RichTextBox in the Controls), it will through a cast error:

System.InvalidCastException:
'Unable to cast object of type
 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 

'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox'.'

I was expecting the foreach to avoid non-RichTextBox controls.
I could naturally filter the controls by TypeOf, but it seems to be unnecessary when the foreach is expected to do the work.

Any explanation??

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. (VS tags are intended for questions about Visual Studio, an integrated development environment).

Comment: _"Any explanation??"_ -> foreach doesn't work like that.

Comment: You should filter the controls of `RichTextBox` before accessing them. `OfType<RichTextBox>` will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring your loop invariant as `RichTextBox` does *not* filter your datasource. it just tells your program that it can safely asume that it will get a RichTextBox.

What you want to use is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1)

```
foreach(var rtb in groupBoxOutputs.Controls.OfType<RichTextBox>())
{
    rtb.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    rtb.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Franz Gleichmann. It works OK the way you suggested. 
Looking at the c# foreach specifications, it can work the way I used with any Type, if:
It has the public parameterless GetEnumerator method whose return type is either class, struct, or interface type,
the return type of the GetEnumerator method has the public Current property and the public parameterless MoveNext method whose return type is Boolean.
So, the problem does not seem to be in the way I used it, but rather with the Types I used.
It would have also worked OK if all controls were of the expected type.